# PHP return true server time?

Tags: php, codeigniter, time

Using codeigniter I have a model to deal with time related functions. I use `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` so that all time functions are based on london time instead of the server time (US based). However, some times I need to know the server time. I tried creating a variable `$server_time = time();` in the construct, preceding the timezone set, but when I refer to it within a function I just get London time returned. Like so...

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    // server time
    $this->server_time = time(); 

    // set base time for all php time() functions!
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
}

public function serverTime(){
   return $this->server_time; // returns London time not server time
}
```

How can I get the actual, true server time?

Comment: If you know the server location, then it's just a matter of converting? Anyways, most servers use GMT anyway

Comment: time will give you local system time try with date() only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will execute the `date` command in shell:

```
echo shell_exec( 'date' );
```

This will give you the time as if you typed it in the command line on the server;

Comment: This works thanks. What's the best way of formatting the date time it returns and making it a bit more human friendly?

Comment: I formatted the time as follows but it doesn't seem a very efficient method?

    `$sdate = explode(' ', shell_exec( 'date' ));
        $stime = explode(':', $sdate[3]);
        $server_time = mktime($stime[0], $stime[1], $stime[2], date('n', time()), trim($sdate[2]), trim($sdate[5]));`

Comment: @Ally: I recommend researching PHP DateTime. I am assuming you are using PHP 5.2 or higher.  It will be your loyal friend if you work with dates in PHP. `$dateObj = new DateTime(shell_exec('date'));

echo $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to store the offset between the two timezones instead of the actual value of time():

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $diff_time = time(); 
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $this->diff_time = $diff_time-time(); 
}

public function serverTime(){
   return time()+$this->diff_time;
}
```

Comment: No that still gives me London time as the `time()` function gets overruled by `date_default_timezone_set()` which ever order you put them in.